# Unable to Run Vue Js Project From Command Prompt

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to run my vue js project but the problem is when I enter server name (main.js) , It is showing following errors message .
[image]

Here is my project structure.

[image]

Comment: How are you training to run your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to start `main.js` with `node main.js`, but that file is located under the `src` subdirectory in your screenshot (i.e., the command should've been `node src/main.js`).

But that directory structure looks like a Vue CLI generated project, so you should instead be using the [NPM scripts](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html) (see `package.json` for available scripts) to start the development server:

```
npm run serve
```